# advise connecting mongodb and uniqush

Tags: android, mongodb, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, middleware

I have a android and IOS shopping app to which I need to send push notifications whenever a new promotion is stored in the db. We have mongodb as our database and we setup uniqush as our push notification server. Now, I need advise on building a robust integration system that polls the offers document collection in the db and sends it to Uniqush over http. What technologies/frameworks should I use and is there any open-source ready-made system?
I have tried simple implementation of Meteor Livequery but it is not suitable to handle more than 100K users that use this app.
We are running on CentOS distribution
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a system ready for that, but there's a variety of languages out there with libs for mongodb and some with clients for uniqush. I worked on a simple [ruby wrapper for uniqush](http://github.com/rafaelbandeira3/uniqush-rb). [Mongoid](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid) is the most popular MongoDB client for ruby.

You can build a system that relies on chronjobs pulling the newest documents from mongo every few minutes, or you can use [Resque](http://github.com/resque/resque) to enqueue a job to run on the background to generate and request push notifications to the uniqush-push server every time a offer is created.

Resque would be a my preferred option as it's pretty standard and straightforward.

Now, you may find ruby being too slow for your user base, then you can try to use golang, which is the same language as uniqush-push--though this is completely irrelevant, which is a really fast language and have all required libs to connect to mongo and you can create a client for uniqush-push fairly simply with the net/http standard lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to integrate 3rd party libraries like MixPanel, Parse
They all support push notifications and also Android\iOS easy integrates with them.
They can handle that amount of notifications, and always you can send not
all at once, but maybe few as a batch.

Comment: Thanks I already have messaging server, the Uniqush. what frameworks should I use to perform database polling and pushing to Uniqush that would best support concurrency and distributed development.